# Python factorial that requires "while" loop

Tags: python

I am a python student that's new to python and I am required to write a program that calculates the factorial of an input number to find the possible ways to arrange letters in a Scrabble game with only the "while" loop construct.
For example: I request for an input number from a user through a line like this initially:

```
n = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
```

and afterwards i need to go about finding the entire factorial with a loop. How do I go about doing this? Below is my entire code and can someone tell me what's wrong with it? It just keeps printing a value of 20:

```
number_of_letters = int(input("Enter the numbers of letters you have in hand:"))
n = number_of_letters

def factorial(number_of_letters):
    while number_of_letters > 1:
        a = number_of_letters
        n = n - 1
        result = a * n
        print('The number of combination for {}-letters words is {}'.format(number_of_letters, result))  # To display output
        break
        return result  # Do not remove this line
```

Comment: try printing out a and n in each iteration

Comment: The program implements an incorrect algorithm. Make sure with some examples that it gives you the result you want. There will be a few changes.

Comment: But first, fix the indentation of your code. What can be seen now is not valid Python. And then tell us what goes wrong with your code. Do you get an error? (WHAT error?) Do you see nothing? Does smoke come out of the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are comparing `number_of_letters > 1` while decreasing `n` and keeping `number_of_letters` without changes.

Also, i don't know what are you trying to archive with the `break` statement, and the return statement should be inside the function but outside the while